# Replacing Core Classes in Codeigniter 4?

Tags: codeigniter-4

i want to create new function in core class CI4, i found this topic here https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/extending/core_classes.html

but i got this error in the image. in the codeigniter 3, its easy do it with "MY_" prefix, but CI4 i dont know how to do it.
[image]

Comment: [Please do not post images of code/error messages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Comment: Whats the purpose of extending the core classes? Can you describe what you are trying to achieve and it is bit difficult to understand your question by looking at the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `echo` and `return view` together

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.